# How can I use firefox on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, heroku, watir, buildpack

I am using watir webdriver and its headless functionality along with firefox browser to goto a website, say `www.xyz.com`.Click on different buttons and download a pdf.I have achieved this in my local environment.When i push my app to heroku, it asked for buildpacks.I have added buildpacks and they are present in my heroku.I found this by running `heroku run bash`.
Dependencies used are:

```
gem 'watir-webdriver', '~> 0.9.1'
gem 'headless', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.3'
Buildpack of Xvfb
Buildpack of firefox
```

Xvfb buildpack is working fine.When running                                `browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => profile)` , I am getting strange errors like `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)`
or `set path for firefox`. I have set path for firefox `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='vendor/firefox/firefox-bin'`
.I can see the firefox installed in that location in my `heroku bash`.
I am not sure whether this is a heroku problem or buildpack problem.Although the develper of buildpack said he was not able to run his  `firefox buildpack` on heroku but he was able to deploy on `Amazon EC2`.Is is possible to install and use firefox with all its functionalities(like opening and closing browser, downloading pdf, opening tabs) on heroku? I am sorry if I am not too clear with my question.
[Firefox Buildpack](https://github.com/bensomers/firefox-buildpack).

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    download_directory = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{dir_name}"

    Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='vendor/firefox/firefox-bin'
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
    profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2 # custom location
    profile['browser.download.dir'] = download_directory
    profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf"
    # Disable built-in pdf viewer of Firefox browser
    profile['pdfjs.disabled'] = true
    profile['pdfjs.firstRun'] = false

    headless = Headless.new
    headless.start

    browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => profile)
    # browser.screenshot.save "pp.png"
    browser.goto 'xyz.com'
    browser.window.resize_to(some_x,some_y)
    browser.text_field(:name => "some_name").set("#{some_data}")
    browser.text_field(:name => "some_password").set("#{password}")
    browser.button(:name => "button").click
    #Pdf gets downloaded in the defined location
    #some database updations
    headless.destroy
  end
rescue => r
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Firefox as headless browser on heroku. Heroku does not support this functionality. You can use some JavaScript browser like [Phantom js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs).

You can configure buildpack for pantom js on heroku.
You need to make some code changes like:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::PhantomJS.path = 'path_to_phantomjs'
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 180 # seconds – default is 60
args = %w{--ignore-ssl-errors=true}
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, :http_client => client, :args => args
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir @Dipak G. I tried your script.I have also tried phantomjs previously but failed because i was unable to figureout `file download using phantomjs`.I made lot of google search and some older posts told me that file download is not possible using `phantomjs`.I have no idea how to solve this problem which also works on `Heroku`.I have to download a pdf file from a website.I don't have its link as it is 302(javascript redirect).I am not sure whether this can be achieved using mechanize gem.Please suggest me possible solutions to this problem.